# Any way that to cut only number or char from the string in php

Tags: php

Does anyone know how can I cut only number or char from the string in php?

### Example

```
$test = '12b';
```

any way that I can only cut the number from the variable: 12?
also and way that I can only cut out the char: b?

NOTE: the $test string flexible to changed.. means it could come with '123b', '1a'...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
  $test='12b'; 

  // ...

  $numeric = preg_replace('/[^\d]/', '', $test);
  echo $numeric; // 12

  $alpha = preg_replace('/[^a-z]/i', '', $test);
  echo $alpha; // b
```

This will work for any combination of characters. All the digits will appear in $numeric, and all latin alphabet letters will appear in $alpha.

This will still work if the letters and numbers are reversed, or if other symbols appear in the string.

Answer (score 2):

[`preg_match`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match.php) could be made use of:

```
<?php

$test = '12b';
preg_match( '/^(\d+)(\w+)$/', $test, $matches );
$digits     = $matches[1];
$characters = $matches[2];

?>
```

Comment: What about replacing `\w` with `\D`?

Comment: `\D` would match anything that does not match `\d`. However, the question demands *characters* only. Hence, `\w`. :-)